# Difficult sequence

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence, calculation-puzzle

Here I go :

> $3 + 5 + 6 = 15 \ 18 \ 72$
>   $5+ 5 + 6 = 25 \ 30 \ 94$
>   $5 + 6 + 7 = 30 \ 35 \ 85$
>   $5 + 5 + 3 = 25 \ 15 \ 73$
>   $9 + 4 + 7 = 36 \ 63 \ ? $

Replace **?** with appropriate number

Comment: Do you mean digit or number?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answer is

> $29$

Explanation:

> The formula is:
>  $a + b + c = a*b \quad a*c\quad ((a*b) + (a*c)) - c$
>
>  Take the example of the first row
>  $3 + 5 + 6 = 15$ $18$ $72$
>  Let $a = 3, b = 5 , c = 6$
>
>  $((3*5) + (3*6)) - 6 \Rightarrow (15 + 18) - 6 \Rightarrow 33 - 6 \Rightarrow 27$
>  Reverse of $27$ is $72$
>
>  In the same way for the last row
>  For $9 + 4 + 7 = 36$ $63$ $?$
>
>  $((9*4) + (9*7)) - 7 \Rightarrow (36 + 63) - 7 \Rightarrow 99 - 7 \Rightarrow 92$
>  reverse of $92$ is $29$

Answer (score 0):

for the missing value

> 173.32

because

> for the third column I get $$26.4 * a - 0.6*b + 7c -3.08ab$$

Comment: I thinnk you are unnecessarily making it more difficult.

Comment: simpler or more complex is in the eye of the beholder.